# What temperature should an Intel Core-i5 750 CPU have, while in idle, and in full load?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cooler

I've heard that the stock cooler the Intel Core-i5 750 comes with is not very efficient. What temperatures are normal under regular operating conditions and under full load for this type of CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the i5 and I like to keep it around 32 to 35 idle and roughly 55 to 60 max when full load.

The [**official**](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?spec=SLBLC) statement is the max temp is 72 C

[Toms Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/lga-1156-heatsink,2535.html) has a good guide for cooling with air, you might check that out for better cooling.

Answer (score 1):

Hi it depends on the cooler you use. My experience with the box cooler ( the one i got with the cpu box) is 42 celsius idle and up to 72 celsius in full load. I personally consider the 72 a little bit high so i will be bying a better cooler.

Comment: My temperatures are nearly identical.